# Why the name 'Request' does not exist when writing in a class.cs file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to move the following piece of code from a c# aspx.cs file into a stand alone class.cs file.

```
string getIP = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(getIP)) getIP = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

This piece of code used to reside in the page_load of an aspx.cs file worked just fine, but it raises an error in the class file.

The 'Request' needs no 'using' when in a aspx.cs file, and offers none in this context.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[Request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.request.aspx) is a property of the page class. Therefore you cannot access it from a "standalone" class.

However, you can get the HttpRequest anyway via [`HttpContext.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx)

```
 var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
```

Note that this works even in a static method. But only if you're in a HttpContext(hence not in a Winforms application). So you should ensure that it's not `null`:

```
if (HttpContext.Current != null)
{
    var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
}
```

**Edit**: Of course you can also pass the request as parameter to the method that consumes it. This is good practise since it doesn't work without. On this way every client would know immediately whether this class/method works or not.

Comment: +1, but in these cases I usually prefer the method hosting the code to require an HttpContext as a parameter argument (or similar construct). I'd like to see something in the public interface for the type that this code expects a web context.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is because you cannot access server variables in a class library project.

You should avoid attempting to make this act like a web class and instead pass the information you need to the class object via a normal parameter.