# Request does not exist in the razor pages

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304782/how-to-get-current-page-url-in-mvc-3) to use URL among my razor view.

but unfortunately I have this compiler error:

> the name 'Request' does not exist in the current context

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439709/why-the-name-request-does-not-exist-when-writing-in-a-class-cs-file) too, but still `HttpContext.Current.Request` is unknown for compiler!

**SOLUTION:**

I used `@Context.Request.Path` and the issue solved. thanks to [Xinran Shen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17438579/xinran-shen)

Comment: Are you using Asp.net Core Razor Page? And you wanna get the current url in the frontend?

Comment: Have you tried to use `<h1>@Context.Request.Path</h1>` ?

Comment: Hi @R.S, I also provide the other method that can get the whole path(include host), Hope it can help you solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your razor view, You use:

```
@Context.Request.Path
```

to get the current request path directly. If you wanna get the whole request path(include host), you can use

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions

@Context.Request.GetEncodedUrl()
```

[image]

[image]

Hope it can solve your issue.